# Pass shared variable from main report to crosstab?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I want to pass shared variable in main report to a subreport's crosstab formula field ? How do I do this ?

If I declare a shared variable inside main report and try to access it in the subreport's crosstab with 'whilereadingrecords' it just won't get anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a mock report and came up with this solution:

- Make a formula in your main report.  Enter this code:

> ```
> whileprintingrecords;
> shared numbervar foo:=3;
> foo
> ```

- In your subreport, make a formula.  For this example, call it `MySharedVar`. Enter this code:

> shared numbervar foo

- In your subreport, make a *second* formula.  Call it `MySharedVar2`. Enter this code:

> MySharedVar

- Use the `MySharedVar2` formula in your crosstab as normal.

Comment: when you would use 'WhilePrintingRecords' in crosstab formula you won't be able to access the shared variable because it must be evaluated later.

Comment: I know what you're getting at, so I crossed out that line and it still works. I've just made a blank report, followed the instructions above, and use MySharedVar2 as a normal variable.